# How to show snippet of an event when clicked in the calendar in Drupal 7 with the Calendar Module

Tags: views

I created a calendar with the Calendar Module, but I don't know what to do to show a snippet of the event when clicked. This calender is a perfect example of what I mean https://hutchinscenter.fas.harvard.edu/calendar. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably many different ways of doing it.

One possibility is the [Calendar Tooltips](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar_tooltips) module.

Another is using Colorbox module to control the popup, you construct the Views output yourself so that the Colorbox library displays it as a popup: [Does Calendar Popup Module exist in D7?](https://www.drupal.org/node/1107890#comment-7154190), [using-colorbox-display-event-details-popup](http://modulesunraveled.com/calendar/using-colorbox-display-event-details-popup)